Entering time on tkinter
please tell me how you can enter time in tkinter in the format “HH:MM”, which can then be used as, for example, a variable.
For example, if I have a condition that if time is greater or less than this variable, then it will be like this, otherwise like this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

no, I don't need the current time, I need to enter the time myself, which will then be used as a variable, for example, enter the delivery time of something

Here is a program where you can input text using tkinter. I hope the comments help explain it. I also added a screenshot: Screenshot of the program in action
from tkinter import *

def submit(): # This function prints the value currently contained in the text box
    text = textBox.get() # This extracts the text written in textBox
    print(text)

window = Tk()

textBox = Entry(window) # Declaring an entry object related to window
textBox.place(x = 10, y = 10) # Adding entry object to window at coordinates x = 10, y = 10

# Here, I declare a submit button. It is related to the window, its text is "Submit" and, if clicked, executes the submit command.
submit_button = Button(window, 
                      text = "Submit",
                      command = submit)
submit_button.place(x = 10, y = 50) # Adding button to window at coordinates x = 10, y = 50

window.mainloop() # Activating window


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
